# Changes to point to the New Ant

Tags: ant, centos, environment

I have a newer ANT in /usr/local/ant .... when did "which ant" it showed me that its still pointing to the default ANT "usr/bin/ant" installed with the Centos 5.8. How do i change it ?

Have tried the following changes, but no luck:

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip
echo 'export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip' >> /etc/bashrc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your valid path as a first one in PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/ant/bin:$PATH
```

See [this article](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch06_04.htm) for more details.

Comment: I'm glad. If that worked, can I ask you to mark this answer as valid? Thanks.